# Internal load balance in vpc of ec2 instances on thrfit services

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, thrift

We have our two servers hosted in VPC of Amazon EC2. One of them is serving one thrift service and another web server which is using it and doing some other stuff.  I am trying to use load balancer on thrift service .Right now this configuration is completely internal .i.e web server can access thrift server internally (without going out and coming in again) . 
Now we want to run multiple thrift servers and put some load balancing in between them such that none of traffic goes outside . Can i do this with ELB of ec2 ?
Does ELB works on internal tcp services ? Any tutorial will help .

Comment: Did you actually get this running?

Comment: no.  EC2 teams says that they have internal load balance which accept tcp connections,but i  coudnt try it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I saw the option to select TCP instead of HTTP inside their new OpsWorks environment. But I also found it's probably better to do it on the client side with round-robing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some trouble load balancing Thrift services w/ ELB. I'm not positive, but I think that ELB's 60 second timeout on inactive connections was the source of the problem. This timeout does not appear to be configurable.

Perhaps someone else can chime in with a better explanation.
A